# Font Awsome not showing correctly

Tags: macos

I installed Font Awsome in my Mac font library. However, when an icon is chosen and transferred to my PPT, it is showing a different image. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add more info to question. But anyway. You have to use UTF-8 codes for Font-Awesome to display properly and font must be selected with FontAwesome.

Comment: I doubt it wont run on ppt. I used font awesome only on web pages.

Comment: fixed spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have font installed, then go to web below, find icon you want and copy image (not code!) and use it. Works for me and others as well!

http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

Forget managing files and start using icons right away. Use CDN to deliver a cached version of Font Awesome to your project.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
```